# NodeJS or NGINX for Reverse Proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, proxy

I'm restructuring a project to use Gulp, Bower, NPM, and AngularJS. The current architecture uses JavaScript MVC served with NGINX, which proxy's all requests to the backend (JAVA). There will be no changes to the backend services, but since the front-end architecture will be using NPM, does it make sense to switch the NGINX proxy server to NodeJS? Is NGINX a better choice for a proxy server than NodeJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx is definitely a better choice for a proxy server than Node.js.
Correctly configured, Nginx will work faster and use less resources. Also, Nginx is standard choice for such tasks and has many production-ready modules out of the box (such as rate-limiting, load balancing, gzip, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, NodeJS is more suited for the backend i.e., if we were going to replace the existing backend services, correct?

Comment: @neridaj yes, it is good as a platform for creating custom backend services.